# Create and sign JWT in Scala for Apple AppStore Connect

Tags: ios, scala, jwt, app-store-connect

i want to create a JWT in a scala application for talking to the Apple's [AppStore Connect api](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/generating_tokens_for_api_requests). i'm following the guide [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/generating_tokens_for_api_requests)

i'm getting an invalid signature on jwt.io when creating a JWT with the below code. a request to appstore connect results in a 401

i can verify that the JWT encodes the header and payload correctly on http://jwt.io

looking at [this](https://github.com/ethanhuang13/CupertinoJWT/blob/34f93f0ead86f3b93405a9d64b1c2206209af273/README.md) library, i think i'm selecting the correct curve algorithm:

> After creating the token, one must sign it with an Apple-provided private key, using the Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm (ECDSA) with the P-256 curve and the SHA-256 hash algorithm, or ES256.

i'm not sure what is wrong - maybe i'm not generating the `S` value correctly?

```
  def generateJWT(): String = {
    val privateKeyBytes: Array[Byte] =
      Base64.getDecoder.decode("base64 representation of private key")
    val S = BigInt(privateKeyBytes)
    
    val curveParams = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("P-256")
    val curveSpec: ECParameterSpec =
      new ECNamedCurveSpec("P-256", curveParams.getCurve(), curveParams.getG(), curveParams.getN(), curveParams.getH());
    val privateSpec = new ECPrivateKeySpec(S.underlying, curveSpec)

    val privateKey =
      KeyFactory.getInstance("EC").generatePrivate(privateSpec)

    val unixTimestamp: Long = Instant.now.getEpochSecond
    val fiveMins = unixTimestamp.toInt + 300

    val header = Map[String, Object](
      "kid" -> "appstore connect Key Identifier",
      "typ" -> "JWT",
      "alg" -> "ES256"
    )

    val payload = Map[String, Object](
      "iss" -> "issuer ID from the API Keys page in App Store Connect",
      "aud" -> "appstoreconnect-v1",
      "exp" -> new Integer(fiveMins)
    )

    Jwts
      .builder()
      .setHeaderParams(header.asJava)
      .setClaims(payload.asJava)
      .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.ES256, privateKey)
      .compact()
  }
```

Comment: where did you get the "invalid signature" error? When you actually used the token or just when you checked it on jwt.io?

Comment: yes, when i checked on jwt.io. a request to appstore connect gives a 401. will update my question

Comment: When you checked on jwt.io, did you provide the public key? Or does the token contain enough information (issuer url, keyId) so that jwt.io can get the public key from an endpoint? Pwoplw often think the signature is invalid, but without knowing the public key, jwt.io can't verify.

Comment: i can see the header and payload is correct without providing the public key. it seems i can't enter the public key without also entering the private key on jwt.io and i didn't want to do that

Comment: select the algorithm in the dropdown, then paste the public key into the public key field in the right columns and finally paste the token that you created with your code into the field on the left. You really odn't need the private key for that.

Comment: that's what i did... i wasn't sure if it was working or not cos it doesn't give much feedback. it says "invalid signature" but it says that before you enter the public key also ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: ok, if you did it exactly like I said above, then it confirms that either the key doesn't match or is just broken.

Comment: i had to generate the public key since apple don't provide you with one. i did it with:

`openssl ec -in private-key.p8 -pubout -out public_key.p8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest two things to try out:

1. `JwtBuilder signWith(SignatureAlgorithm var1, Key var2)` is deprecated. Can you try using `JwtBuilder signWith(Key var1, SignatureAlgorithm var2)` , and see if that succeeds?
2. If not, you can try using [bountycastle](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on) , which does work for me. Following is the code snippet for getting the private key.

```
  def getPrivateKey(): PrivateKey = {

    val pemParser = new PEMParser(new FileReader(<Your Apple-AuthKey file with extension .p8>))
    val converter = new JcaPEMKeyConverter
    val privateKeyInfo = pemParser.readObject.asInstanceOf[PrivateKeyInfo]
    val pKey = converter.getPrivateKey(privateKeyInfo)
    pemParser.close()
    pKey
  }
```

Comment: what does your build.sbt look like to get that dependency?

Comment: i've added `"org.bouncycastle" % "bcprov-jdk15on" % "1.68"` but it can't find `PEMParser` for example

Comment: Its the one that I linked to. I am using them directly via Intellij Library and Artifacts.
"org.bouncycastle" % "bcpkix-jdk15on" % "1.68"
I see this is the only dependency related to bountycastle in my project

Comment: It is "bcpkix" and not "bcprov" .

Comment: you are my saviour, thank you! 

for the record solution 2 worked for me!